# Installing and Using PIL 1.1.7 on OS 10.9.5 Marvericks

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, python-imaging-library

I have just started learning Python Programing and tried to install PIL on MacOS 10.9.5 Marvericks using pip(1.5.6).

Of course I referred to other same question about installing PIL, but I cannot figure out my problem.

> _imagingft.c:73:10: fatal error: 'freetype/fterrors.h' file not found
>
> **#include freetype/fterrors.h
>
> ```
>      ^
> ```
>
> 1 error generated.
>
> error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

The error occurred like above.

I add

> ln -s /usr/local/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/freetype

and the terminal shows

> ln: /usr/local/include/freetype: File exists

and next I add

> pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL

but the same error remains.

I already installed Xcode(6.1), X11(2.7.7).
The freetype is Ver. 2.5.3_1.
Python is Ver. 2.7.6.

I would appreciate if you could teach what should I do.